# how to integrate pyspark on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark

i have followed instructions to integrate pyspark with jupyter but after i was done i was only able to run pyspark on the command prompt .

Basically when i am using ipython in my command it is working but when i change to jupyter it says

```
'"Jupyter "' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

please SO people i am really exhausted now , please help

note : i followed [this](http://jmdvinodjmd.blogspot.in/2015/08/installing-ipython-notebook-with-apache.html) tutorial to do my integration .

till now i have followed this command :

```
  set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython 
  set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = notebook 
  pyspark
```

it opens pyspark in cmd itself

Comment: Please post your command/script/whatever, I think I can help you.

Comment: sure i am editing now thanks :)

Comment: i have downloaded the pre-build spark

Comment: it is on windows right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows `set` command does not accept spaces before the `=` sign.

fix this like that:

```
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython 
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook 
pyspark
```

The system wants to run the `"Jupyter %PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS%"` executable but instead tries to run '"Jupyter "'

hence the error you're getting.

Comment: it worked , oh my god i have spent last three hours learning 20 documentations and finally it worked !!! thanks @jean